# C# How to call overloaded operator in generic parent class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

Following problem:
In the definition of an function of a generic parent class ParentA I want to call an overloaded operator from ChildB:

See the following structure

```
class ParentA<T> where T : ParentB
{
    public bool Contains(T element)
    {
             T element2;
         return element==element2;
    }
}

class ChildB : ParentB
{
     public static bool operator ==(ChildB s1, ChildB s2)
     {
      //this one should be used
     }
}


ChildA :ParentA<ChildB>
{
//make use of inherited function Contains(ChildB element)
}
```

I want to call the overloaded == operator of ChildB, but instead when I call the Contains function in ChildA the original ==operator from ParentB will be called.

Any idea how to make this work?

### The Original code is a bit more nasty

```
public abstract class ElementBase
{
    protected Element element;
    public Element Element
    {
        get { return element; }
        set { element = value; }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ElementBase e1, ElementBase e2)
    {
        return e1.element == e2.element;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(ElementBase e1, ElementBase e2)
    {
        return e1.element != e2.element;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj == null) || !this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
            return false;
        else
        {
            ElementBase element = (ElementBase)obj;
            return this == element;
        }
    }
}

public class Structure : ElementBase
{
    public bool flag;
    public static bool operator ==(Structure s1, Structure s2)
    {
        return s1.element == s2.element  && s1.flag==s2.flag;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Structure s1, Structure s2)
    {
        return s1.element != s2.element || s1.flag!=s2.flag;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj == null) || !this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
            return false;
        else
        {
            Structure structure = (Structure)obj;
            return this == structure;
        }
    }
}

public class MapBase<T> where T : ElementBase
{
    protected Dictionary<long, T> elements = new Dictionary<long, T>();
    public bool Contains(T element)
    {
        ...
        return element==elements[id];
    }
}

public class StructureMap : MapBase<Structure>
{
       void someFunction()
       {
            //make use of Contains(Structure element)
       }

}
```

---

**Update**

I replaced

```
return element==element2;
```

by

```
return element.Equals(element2);
```

and now it seems like it does the trick. I just don't understand why...

Comment: Can you show the code which is trying to use the overloaded operator? Also the code of ParentB class?

Comment: Are you trying to somehow invoke `==` from the base class? I think that's impossible to do directly, but you can override `Equals` in the base class and call it from the `==` operator, then `base.Equals` should work.

Comment: The operator methods are static type that's why those are resolved at compile time instead of run time. so you need to provide the definition of operator in `ParentB`

Comment: @user1672994   how should I define an operator in ParentB which is acting on childB?

Comment: Your ==operator, will only be called, if at compile time is known, that both things you compare are of Type ParentB. Otherwise the signature of the operator wouldn' match.
If you want the second parameter to be just anything (like in Equals) you have to give it type object also.